# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger none of the debugger member or watch expressions returns values

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, remote-desktop

When I debug a remote website on a server I got not value form any of the debugger member or watch expressions all I got is “Internal error in the expression evaluator” if I tried to inspect any variable on QuickWatch window.

I tried changing the value on Tools | Options | Debugger | General | Use Managed Compatibility Mode to true like some people suggest but then I cannot Attach to Process I get the error message Unable to attach to the process. The RPC server is unavailable.

I’m using Visual Studio Update3 and Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger Version 14.0.25424 and I trying to debug an asp.net website.

Comment: Please check "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators" under tools->Options->Debugging, how about the result? As you said that you debug your app remotely, did you debug it locally? How about the result?

Comment: It worked!  

Can you repost your comment as an answer? so I can accept this as the right answer.

Comment: Glad to know that it resolved this issue, I post the comment as the answer, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Internal error in the expression evaluator.

Please check "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators" under tools->Options->Debugging, and then you can view the variable on debug window.